# Добавление элемента в Tree<E>

Tags: java

Добрый день. Задача "Создать элементарную структуру дерева". У меня возникли трудности с добавлением элемента, понимаю что возможно нужно как то рекурсивно проходить по дереву. Нужно найти в дереве элемент `parent`, если у него нет таких `child`, добавить ему входящий `child`. Тут `root` - это корень дерева.

```
public boolean add(E parent, E child) {
    if (root.eqValue(parent)) {            //если наш корень это parent
        if (!root.contain(child)) {       //и в нем нет такого child, добавляем в него child
            root.add(new Node<>(child));
            modCount++;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        //если parent не корень, что делать?
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ну, вам требуется реализовать функцию поиска в дереве этого самого `parent`; потом в месте, где вы указали комментарий сослаться на эту функцию. Алгоритм поиска рекурсивный: смотрите дочерние элементы корня, если нету нужного, смотрите дочерние элементы дочерних элементов

Comment: Я понимаю в теории, что делать, я не знаю как в коде это оформить, потому что у меня в итоге получается что я иду по самой крайней ветке слева, потом выхожу из цикла. а надо чтобы я все ветки проверил

Answer (score 1):

```java
private Boolean add(Node node, E parent, E child) {
  if (node.eqValue(parent)) { // если наш узел это parent
    if (!node.contain(child)) { // и в нем нет такого child, добавляем в него child
      node.add(new Node<>(child));
      modCount++;
      return true;  // Если добавили - вернем true
    } else
      return false;  // Если нашли, но не добавили - вернем false
  } else {
    for (Node childNode : node) {  // Цикл по всем потомкам
      Boolean res = add(childNode, parent, child);
      if (res != null)  // Если узел нашли
        return res;  // то выходим
    }
    // Если попали сюда, то ничего не нашли
    return null;
  }
}

public boolean add(E parent, E child) {
  // Пытаемся добавить в корень, а там как пойдет
  Boolean res = add(root, parent, child);
  return res != null;  // Если элемент был найден, вернем true
}
```